# ClickOnce application settings best practice?

Tags: clickonce

I'm using ClickOnce and have some local settings to store.
My problem is I would like them to be removed on uninstall which as I understand it rules out the registry?

So I can save them into a file but am not sure where to save it to so that it will be removed on uninstall.

My conundrum is I would like the settings to remain at the same location when the application gets updated each time round so my app will continue to work.
Hope you can help, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store settings with application scoped isolated storage. This will be removed on uninstall.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202013) for details.