# How to use IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I have a clickonce app and it works fine in production, with method:

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
```

which executes successfully.
When I try to debug my application it crashes with IsolatedStorageException because of "The application identity of the caller cannot be determined.." [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforapplication?view=netframework-4.7)

> All assemblies associated with an application use the same isolated store when using this method. This method can be used only when the application identity can be determined - for example, when the application is published through ClickOnce deployment or is a Silverlight-based application. If you attempt to use this method outside a ClickOnce or Silverlight-based application, you will receive an IsolatedStorageException exception, because the application identity of the caller cannot be determined.

My question is how to use IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() and debug application without exceptions?

- Probably do some checks?
- or use custom application identity?
- or use IsolatedStorageFile.GetEnumerator to get avalible stores?

Comment: check if activation context is null first, which would indicate that the domain has no activation context meaning the application identity of the caller cannot be determined

Comment: I would also suggest abstracting out the IsolatedStorage so that testing can be done in isolation without knock on effects

Comment: answers here also proved helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694201/5233410

Comment: Thanks, I end up with check for ActivationContext and fallback to GetUserStoreForAssembly if not posible to do GetUserStoreForApplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if activation context is null first,

```
public IsolatedStorageFile getIsolatedStorage() {
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ActivationContext == null
        ? IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()
        : IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
}
```

which would indicate that the domain has no activation context meaning the application identity of the caller cannot be determined.

I also saw another implementation

Reference [ClickOnce and IsolatedStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694201/5233410)

where they checked `System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetwor‌​kDeployed` to determine if the application was currently click once deployed

```
public IsolatedStorageFile getIsolatedStorage() {
    return System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationDeployment.IsNetwor‌​kDeployed
        ? IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
        : IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly();
}
```

Ideally I would also suggest encapsulating the `IsolatedStorage` behind an abstraction  so that unit testing can also be done in isolation without knock on effects.